# Dual validation with a do-while loop and if-else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I need to figure out how to validate 2 conditions.

1. Check if a previous number has been played.
2. Check if the number is between 1 and 9.

In either case, it should loop back to the beginning. With the first situation, it shouldn't run till the user enters a number that hasnt been played.

```
do
{
  cout << "Interesting move, What is your next choice?: ";
  cin >> play;
  Pused[1] = play;

  if(play != Pused[0] && play != cantuse[0] && play != cantuse[1] )
  {
    switch(play)
    {
      default:
        cout << "Your choice is incorrect\n\n";
        break;
    }   
  }
}while(play != 1 && play != 2 && play != 3 && play != 4
    && play != 5 && play != 6 && play != 7 && play != 8 && play != 9);

Dis_board(board);
```

Comment: So what isn't working about your code?

Comment: You should really rewrite your `while` condition as `while (play > 0 && play < 10)`...

Comment: @H2CO3: `while (play > 0 && play < 10)` is **not** same as `while(play != 1 && [...] )`

Comment: @Nawaz forgot the `!` operator, but are you not getting what I mean?

Comment: @H2CO3: I got what you meant, but the problem is that I didn't ask the question. The questioner needs to understand what you *meant* rather than what you *wrote*. :-)

Comment: What is `Pused`?  An array of the "already played" values (you're not using it as such)?  And what are `cantuse[0..1]`?

Comment: If the player. lets say enters a number stored in `cantuse[1]` I need it to make them re-enter `play`. If they enter a number thats not 1-9, it should ask them to re -enter as well, im wondering how i can do this.

Comment: `cantuse[]` and `pused{}` are the same thing...its a little redundent. Its a just in case kind of thing... i also use `Pused` later in the code... `cantuse 0 and 1` both store plays used... the user and the computers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of do-while loops, i like to use the combination of infinite loops + `break` statements, like this:

```
cout << "What is your first choice? ";
while (true)
{
    // Input the choice, including validation

    // Do the move

    if (game_over)
        break;

    cout << "Interesting move; what is your next choice? ";
}
```

In the code above, the two comments represent code, which may itself contain loops. In order to reduce confusion, you might want to stuff this code into a separate function. For example, to input the choice:

```
while (true)
{
    cin >> play;
    bool is_illegal =
        play == cantuse[0] ||
        play == cantuse[1] ||
        play < 1 ||
        play > 9;
    if (is_llegal)
        cout << "Your choice is incorrect; please enter again: ";
    else
        break;
}
```

Note: to implement good handling of user errors, you also have to account for the case when the user enters nonsense instead of a number; look up `istream::ignore` and `ios::clear` for that.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!! I appreciate it so much! If theres anything i can do for you name it!

Comment: I actually dislike while(true) loops, it's not exactly clear what you are trying to do until you read the whole loop. I'd rather go for something like while(!(play = read_move())) { ... }